# I want to hide my email address when I send an email from a Lotus Notes Group Email

Tags: email, lotus-notes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the Respond To for Group Email adresses in Notes 6.5](https://superuser.com/questions/412895/how-do-i-change-the-respond-to-for-group-email-adresses-in-notes-6-5)

When I send an email from a group mail box the email shows my email address as the sender.  I would like to hide my email and only show my name.  I am using Notes 6.5.  Could you please advise if there is a way to set up my client to do this.

I want this so the receiver responds to the group email not my personal email as it may be that I am not the one to do the fillow up to the response. There are 10 people in the group email.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: I want this so the receiver responds to the group email not my personal email as it may be that I am not the one to do the fillow up to the response.  There are 10 people in the group email.

Comment: Valid question. Have a look at the Team Mailbox template at OpenNTF. It provides this exact functionality.

Comment: I have provided an answer for your other question at http://superuser.com/questions/412895/how-do-i-change-the-respond-to-for-group-email-adresses-in-notes-6-5

Comment: Ah. In the future @ShaunCasey, if your question gets closed, please edit it to improve it, and then you can ask for it to be reopened. Please don't post a new question altogether, since that makes it hard to keep track of everything. Thanks!