# How do I change the Respond To for Group Email adresses in Notes 6.5

Tags: email, lotus-notes

When I send an email from a group mail box the email shows my email address as the sender on behalf of the group email address.  I would like to hide my email and only show my name as the sender and have the respond to as the group email address rather than my email address. I am using Notes 6.5.  Could you please advise if there is a way to set up my client to do this.

Comment: FYI RFC 822 defines a `Reply-To` field for email messages. This is supported by SMTP as well as pretty much all e-mail clients, so hiding your e-mail address isn't necessary. You just need to set the `Reply-To` address to the group email address. This would also make it less likely that someone confuses the group address as being your personal email address because they see it labeled with your name.

Comment: Notes already correctly addresses replies, but if an ID other than the account owner creates the email, it also adds a 'sent by' field.  People will manually add in the 'sent by' person when they reply instead of allowing their email to just go back to the group inbox. Manually setting a reply-to doesn't help because the problem is user error.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Team Mailbox template on OpenNTF which provides the functionality to be able to respond with a team/group email address instead of your own email address:
http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=8E156950C4FB032686257760006044D1

Comment: Bonus: you should upgrade to Lotus Notes 8.5 which is the latest release. Lotus Notes 6.5 is out of support

Comment: Most people don't use Lotus Notes at all (let alone an outdated version) if they can help it ;)

Comment: I do not agree with that comment

Comment: Presumably the OP isn't an admin so messing about with the mailfile template wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: In that case he could suggest his admin that this is changed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to switch to the ID file of the group account, your administrator should be able to set you up.  Using the group ID and associated location doc will show only the information for the group ID.

If you aren't able to switch, you should be able to set the reply-to address, it won't hide the "sent by" information showing that you created the email, but it will show the group address as the "from" and when they click reply should fill in the correct reply to address.  Honestly, it should be filling in the correct reply to address anyway, but people often manually re-add the sender when they reply preferring to deal with the existing contact instead of going back to the group.